# Kubernetes multinode setup cannot remove docker0 interface

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes, flannel

I setup Kubernetes in multinode mode in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with docker 1.7.1 by following this Guide: 
http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master/

The guide told to `Remove the existing Docker bridge` by

`sudo /sbin/ifconfig docker0 down`
and
`sudo brctl delbr docker0`

everything is good until I restart the host machine (ubuntu), the docker0 interface is recreated after restart and also it sit on the subnet I told in `/etc/default/docker`

any step I missed to stop it recreate the docker0 interface?
or it is suppose to be there?

I am confused.

Comment: that seems right to me: i guess the guide says remove the default docker0 interface so that it can be recreated with the right subnet! You need the docker0 bridge for docker.

Comment: You missed a step which says how to configure your docker service network settings. That step + a tiny extra script to initialize the cbr0 are required to get docker correct at start up of the system

Comment: @MrE you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my original comment:

the docker0 bridge needs to be recreated with the right subnet.

It is originally created by Docker, but Kubernetes needs to defines its own, so it needs to be deleted first.

The script recreates the interface though, which is why it appears again after running it.

This is the normal behavior.